# How to Study Improving In-depth Reading Comprehension?

Tags: natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics

There are multiple datasets for machine comprehension tasks such as [SQuAD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05250.pdf). However, most of the questions are straightforward. One can find the answers easily by using the find feature of the browser to look for the question keywords in the passage.

I'd appreciate it if you let us know about standardized in-depth reading comprehension tests for either human or machine that are generalizable. By generalizable, I mean they include a broad range of disciplines and academic levels and are not specifically designed for a target population.

I thought of GRE reading comprehension but was not able to find any study indicating that GRE reading comprehension questions are standardized or generalizable.

Comment: Hello. It's not fully clear to me what you're asking here. Are you looking for datasets that somehow would be more general than SQuAD? Please, edit your post to clarify what your question really is (i.e. explicitly ask a question) and how it is related to AI. It's not fully clear to me whether this question is about AI or not.

Comment: SQuAD is already generalizable with many questions from Wikipedia articles on a large diversity of topics. My problem with SQuAD, as explained in the question, is the difficulty level of the questions. Most of them are very straightforward to answer. One can easily find the answers by searching the keywords of the question in the passage. We're looking for a dataset of more analytical questions. That's why we were thinking of using the GRE verbal reasoning questions but were not able to find any study indicating that GRE reading comprehension questions are standardized or generalizable.

Comment: So, you're looking for a dataset where the answers to the questions would be so easy to find?

Comment: The opposite, difficult. We're looking for more of analytical questions than straightforward ones.